# How to increase the render distance (fire)

Tags: rendering, camera, smoke-simulation

How to increase render distance of fire effects?
I have big scene (and I can't make it smaller) and I have an explosion in it, but it is to far to be rendered correctly, I can see only flying particles but not fire (in smaller scene it is work fine) what should I do? I have increased clipping.

(I have blender 2,72)

Comment: If you have increased clipping, than make sure so you did enaught. And, what are you using for fire? Is it particle or textured plane?

Comment: Sometimes it is necessary to tweak some settings to make it render at all. Another things is that the fire might be small enough you can't physically see it. Without screenshots it is really a guessing game.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Proporties -> Camera* and increase this number:

[image: Select End in clipping]

Make sure to increase End in Clipping. This will increase camera range!

Comment: But i have increased this, everything is rendering but not fire. Only fire is not rendered.

Comment: OK! But what are you using for fire? Is it mesh or something else?

Comment: particles because it is explosion (quick explode and quick smoke)

Comment: Than... I think so particles aren't rendered on so far distance at all...

Comment: ahh :( so I will try find an other way to solve this problem. thank you :)

Comment: Maybe you can make particles smaller, but locate them a bit closer?

Comment: @Katruf Have you tried emitting the fire from the mesh? With quick explode, the mesh is broken into shards, but it's still there, and the shards follow the trajectory of the particles.

Answer (score 1):

So in case anybody is still fighting with this in 2020, using Eevee, the camera clip distance and volumetric rendering distance are two separate parameters...

1. Render Properties (tab)
2. Volumetrics (panel)
3. Start / End (fields)

The clip end is set to 100 by default, while the camera itself is set to 1000 by default.
Change the Eevee volumetric rendering clip distance to match your camera, or at least far enough to include your volumetric effects!